# C++ Best Practice - Define classes in multiple namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

In C++ you can declare a class and then inject its name in multiple name spaces with the following syntax

```
namespace A
{
class MyT{};
}

namespace B
{
using A::MyT;
}
```

Let's assume that A and B in my code represent different categories of classes  which are not simply subsets of one another and that MyT is actually a class that belongs to both categories.
Is it considered a good practice to define the class name in both namespaces like I showed?
Are there potential disadvantages in this technique?

Thank you in advance

EDIT:
The goal of the using in this case is not to shorten the declaration but to make it more readable in different contexts so that in some places it could be referred as A::MyT and elsewhere as B::MyT, depending on what is the logical meaning of the class in the user context. 
For example, if MyT represents a door and is a shape object whose interface is defined in the Geometry namespace but it's used in the context of the Building namespace, then in some cases it makes sense to use it as Geometry::MyT, in other as Building::MyT.
Of course to reduce the chances of confusion I declared the namespace injection in the same header where the class is declared in its original namespace

Answer (score 4):

You are not "storing" the class in both namespaces. You are simply allowing a `MyT` to be used in `namespace B` without qualifying it as `A::MyT`.

Example:

```
namespace B
{
    using A::MyT;
    MyT myt;     // refers to A::MyT
}
```

Whether you should do so in a real project depends on how likely it is that you think there may be some kind of naming collision with `A::MyT`. Generally, I would say to avoid it. If anything, having to write `A::MyT` instead of `MyT` improves readability, as it makes it obvious to the reader which `MyT` you are referring to.

Comment: If the project is very large, it could actually improve readability.

Comment: @Attersson  Yes, I added that to the answer.

Comment: Yes, indeed storing was the wrong wording.
The goal of the using in this case is not to shorten the declaration but to make it more readable in different contexts so that in some places it could be referred as A::MyT and elsewhere as B::MyT, depending on what is the logical meaning of the class in the user context

Comment: @Triskeldeian Sounds less readable to me.

Answer (score 1):

I will keep my answer as devoid of opinion as possible.

Using one disjoint namespace within another, creates a dependency and some hardcoding because you need to know the used namespace name.

If and only if this is intentional (for example stating an intent), consider it good for your project.

Practically, namespaces are meant to avoid naming collisions. It will ensure that you are accessing the correct entities.